# Why does my Sony Alpha 77 II sometimes change to a lower resolution on its own?

Tags: resolution, sony-a7ii

I've taken about 700 pictures with my new Sony Alpha 77 II, all at the maximum 6000x4000 resolution. However, when I reviewed the pictures afterwards there are a couple at the lower 4240x2832 resolution among them, always a few consecutively. I guess the resolution somehow switched to the lower resolution, and it was restored after I switched the camera off and on again.

I have no idea how this could have happened. Is there a way to unintentionally and temporarily change the resolution without going through the menu? Or could this be a software bug (in which case it should have happened to others as well)?

Comment: Do the lower resolution pictures have anything in common? Were they all taken in a scene mode, or perhaps all taken in continuous shooting mode? I wonder if the camera lowers the resolution to optimise write speed in burst mode.

Comment: @Elendil - Certainly not continuous shooting mode. BTW, it would be a Real Bad Idea to reduce resolution for that; nobody would accept that, and it would cost them customers. Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: absolutely. But it may be an option. I'm just trying to narrow down possibilities.

Comment: Are you using any sort of digital zoom feature? Maybe known as "Smart Teleconverter". I think that just crops the centre part of the image, so will give you lower resolution.

Comment: @vclaw That seems likely — the A77 II _does_ have a digital zoom feature.

Comment: I (and Occam) like the teleconverter-button-press explanation. This will show in EVF but you could alter zoom to compensate in many cases. The mode resets when you view photos you have taken. || However, as an also ran - if you turn the mode selector knob through the MR position it MAY pick up settings  from a memory recall action.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Sony A77 has a Digital 1.4x and a 2x “Smart Teleconverter Feature”.

This feature crops the image with no image quality loss, albeit, at a smaller size cropped from the centre

At full size of 24 Megapixels, you get 6000 x 4000

**When you do a 1.4x Digital Tele-convert you get a 12 Megapixel image which equates to 4240 x 2832**

at 2x Digital Tele-convert, you get a 6 megapixel image, equating to 3008 x 2000

The Toggle button is at the back and it is possible that this has been pressed accidentally.

Comment: And as the TC function is controlled by a single button, which is itself right next to the Fn button, it's probably quite easy to press it inadvertently.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall - spot on

Comment: Interest only: " with no image quality loss," -> on my A77 it's been my impression that I may get better results by using TC than when I post crop to same size. That does not seem to make sense but seems to happen. I should get to doing some controlled playing.